# understanding solution of Valid Anagram in javascript

Tags: javascript, anagram

This is from LeetCode - Valid Anagram

Given two strings s and t , write a function to determine if t is an anagram of s.
Example 1:
Input: s = "anagram", t = "nagaram"
Output: true
Example 2:

You may assume the string contains only lowercase alphabets.

Follow up:
What if the inputs contain unicode characters? How would you adapt your solution to such case?

I don't understand these code below

- result1[s.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++; --> what does ++ mean?
- result2.length = 26; --> what does 26 stand for?
- result2.fill(0); --> why does fill it with 0?

Please advise!

```
var isAnagram = function(s,t) {
    if (s.length !== t.length)
        result false;
    const result1 = [];
    result1.length = 26;
    result1.fill(0);

    const result2 = [];
    result2.length = 26;
    result2.fill(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        result1[s.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++;
        result2[t.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < result1.length; i++) {
        if (result1[i] !== result2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Comment: `console.log(s[i], s.charCodeAt(i) - 97)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's somewhat poorly written code, let's improve it a bit so that your question are automatically gone:

```
var isAnagram = function(string1, string2) {
    if (string1.length !== string2.length)
        return false; // here was a typo: result false

    const alphabetLength = 26;
    // returns an array of zeros (empty counters), each one per alphabet letter
    const getAlphabetCounters = function() {
        const counters = [];
        counters.length = alphabetLength;
        counters.fill(0);
        return counters;
    }
    const countCharacter = function(c, counters) {
        // zero for a, 25 for z
        const position = c.charCodeAt(0) - 97;
        counters[position]++;
    }

    const counters1 = getAlphabetCounters();
    const counters2 = getAlphabetCounters();

    for (let i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
        countCharacter(string1[i], counters1);
        countCharacter(string2[i], counters2);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < counters1.length; i++) {
        if (counters1[i] !== counters2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

But it would be probably a better idea to use a "decremental" approach like this:

```
var isAnagram = function(string1, string2) {
    if (string1.length !== string2.length)
        return false;

    let letters1 = string1.split('');
    let letters2 = string2.split('');
    for (let letter of letters1) {
        let position = letters2.indexOf(letter);
        if(position == -1)
            return false;
        letters2.splice(position, 1);
    }
    return true;
};
```

or if one cares about performance for long strings, sorting letters in those and direct comparison would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

This is my version of solution. You can even skip join() at the end of, since you still can compare two arrays.

```
const isAnagram = function(s, t) {
  if (s.length !== t.length ) {
    return false;
    }
  if (s.split('').sort().join('') === t.split('').sort().join('')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

++ is the increment operator. It can be pre-fixed (++i) or post-fixed (i++). In this case it is post-fixed: `result1[s.charCodeAt(i) - 97]++`, so it will increment the value of `result1[s.charCodeAt(i) - 97]`.

26 is simply the number of letters in the alphabet (from a to z).

The code is initializing the two arrays and `fill`ing them with 0s so that it can use the array elements as counters. Each index in the array represents a letter in the alphabet, and stores the occurrences of that letter in the string.

Answer (score 0):

With minimum array functions and single for loop

```
    function anagram(str1, str2){
        var isAnagram = true;
        if(str1.length != str2.length){
            isAnagram = false;
        }else{
            for(var i=0; i<str1.length;i++) {       
                if(!str2.includes(str1[i])){
                    isAnagram = false;
                }   
            }
        }

        if(isAnagram){
            console.log('string is anagram');
        }else{
            console.log('string is not anagram');
        }
    }

    anagram('READ', 'DEAR');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isAnagram = function(s, t) {
  let sArr = s.split('');
  let tArr = t.split('');

  sArr.sort();
  let newS = sArr.join('');

  tArr.sort();
  let newT = tArr.join('');

  return newS === newT; 
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be nice if you explained you answer for others to find it more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with only one line of code

```js
const isAnagram = (s,t) => ( [...s].sort().join('') === [...t].sort().join(''))

console.log( isAnagram('anagram', 'nagaram') )  // true
console.log( isAnagram('anagram', 'xxx') )     // false
```

But your question also asks to manage all the utf8 characters, which I interpret as having to eliminate the [diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), [for which there is an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript).

that I changed a little to keep only the letters (which excludes spaces and other punctuation), to be able to process anagrams of several words too :

```js
const letters = str => str.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')
```

which has for final solution:

```js
const letters = str => str.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')
  ,   isAnagram = (s,t) => ( [...letters(s)].sort().join('') === [...letters(t)].sort().join(''))
  ;
const anagrams =  // from wikipedia
  [ { s: "evil"
    , t: "vile"                     }
  , { s: "New York Times"
    , t: "monkeys write"            }
  , { s: "William Shakespeare"
    , t: "I am a weakish speller"   }
  , { s: "Le commandant Cousteau"
    , t: "Tout commença dans l'eau" }  // with diacritic ( French )
  , { s: "La crise économique"
    , t: "Le scénario comique"      }
  , { s: "Question sans réponse"
    , t: "Enquêtons sans espoir"    }
  , { s: "Chauve-souris"
    , t: "Souche à virus"           }
  ]

for (let {s,t} of anagrams )
    console.log(`_${s}_, _${t}_ -> `, isAnagram(s,t))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to check for a valid anagram

**Time complexity:** O(n)

**Space complexity:** O(n)

**Method 1:**

```
/**
 * @param {string} str1
 * @param {string} str2
 * @return {boolean}
 */
const isAnagram = (str1, str2) => {
    if(str1.length != str2.length) return false;
    
    const arr1 = str1.split('');
    const arr2 = str2.split('');
    let obj = {};
    
    for(let val of arr1) {
        obj[val] = ++obj[val] || 1;
    }
    
    for(let val of arr2) {
        if(!obj[val]) return false;
        else obj[val] -=1;
    }
    return true;
};
```

**Method 2:**
Smaller solution using pre-defined methods.

```
/**
 * @param {string} str1
 * @param {string} str2
 * @return {boolean}
 */

const isAnagram = (str1, str2) => {
    if(str1.length != str2.length) return false;

    let sortedStr1 = str1.split('').sort().join('');
    let sortedStr2 = str2.split('').sort().join('');

    return sortedStr1 === sortedStr2;
}
```

Comment: Tangential: canonical JS would `return sortedStr1 === sortedStr2` instead.